# asp.net textbox default value

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, textbox

I would like to add a default value for an asp textbox that looks like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Title" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" ClientIDMode="Static"><xsl:value-of select="oohru/form/title"/></asp:TextBox>
```

Reason being is the page called is an xml page which loads this page as the stylesheet.  The XML page once on the client side would transform that xsl select into the appropriate value [Which is an XML element from a previous cross page post].
Of course it ends up escaping it to look like

```
<input class="textEntry" id="Title" value="&lt;xsl:value-of select=&quot;oohru/form/title&quot;/&gt;" name="ctl00$RightColumn$Title" type="text">
```

and the text box instead of having the value contained in the value-of select contains the actual value-select statement since it is escaped.

I tried setting the value in the pageload and got the same results and I tried turning off ValidateRequest neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`<xsl:value-of select="oohru/form/title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`

Edit:

`<asp:TextBox ID="Title" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" ClientIDMode="Static"><xsl:value-of select="oohru/form/title"/></asp:TextBox>`

To become:

`<asp:TextBox ID="Title" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" Text="{oohru/form/title}" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Doesn't do anything.  In fact the generated XSL sheet strips it out completely [the disable part of the line]